# Placement of magento blocks

Tags: php, magento, block

I want to place the product description inside the product image box just under the gallary images.Here is the part of code of my themes catalog.xml.I am placing the block

under

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
```

but its not working.Only the description shows while being placed at the very begining under

```
  <reference name="content">
```

Its not working under any other blocks.I think its clear.

```
<reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
            <!--
            <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/summary.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>short</type><template>review/helper/summary_short.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>...</type><template>...</template></action>
            -->
            <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media"
                   template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" translate="label">
                <label>Alert Urls</label>
            </block>

            <action method="setTierPriceTemplate">
                <template>catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml</template>
            </action>

            <block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs"
                   template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml">

                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
                    <alias>additional</alias>
                    <title>Additional Information</title>
                    <block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block>
                    <template>catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml</template>
                </action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="review">
                    <alias>product_review</alias>
                    <title>Reviews</title>
                    <block>review/product_view_list</block>
                    <template>review/product/view/list.phtml</template>
                </action>
                <block type="cms/block" name="product_custom_tab">
                    <action method="setBlockId">
                        <block_id>product_custom_tab</block_id>
                    </action>
                </block>
            </block>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These block are used to define `WHAT` content have to displayed if you want to change the `placement(WHERE)` You need to change it in the `.phtml` files.

In

```
app/design/frontend/[theme_packahe]/[theme]/template/catalog/product
```

find `view.phtml` and make the modifications(just cut paste) as per your requirements....